# ¿Cómo mostrar un archivo de texto con lineas con diferentes partes y longitudes?

Tags: python

Tengo una pregunta para un trabajo de la universidad.
De qué forma puedo mostrar un archivo por pantalla si las líneas tienen diferentes longitudes, me explico, la primera linea tiene 2 partes:

```
"ESCUELA, CURSO"
```

La segunda tiene 3 partes:

```
"PROFESOR,CANTIDAD DE ALUMNOS,ALUMNOS DESTACADOS"
```

Y la siguiente:

```
"NOMBRE, APELLIDO, EDAD, SEXO, CALIFICACIÓN"
```

Esto me aparece cuando pongo a correr el código de la imagen de abajo.

```
File "/Users/sbaezvergara/Desktop/untitled2.py", line 27, in
<module>
   sexo=partes[3]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Este es el código que he intentado pero no funciona:

```
archivo=open("datos.txt","r")
linea=archivo.readline().strip()
while linea != "":
    partes=linea.split(";")
    escuela=partes[0].upper()
    cursos=int(partes[1])
    print(escuela,curso)
    for i in range(cursos):
        linea=archivo.readline().strip()
        partes=linea.split(";")
        profesor=partes[0].upper
        cantidaddealumnos=partes[1]
        alumnosdestacados=int(partes[2])
        print(profesor,cantidaddealumnos,alumnosdestacados)
        for j in range (cantidaddealumnos):
            nombre=partes[0]
            apellido=partes[1]
            edad=int(partes[2])
            sexo=partes[3]
            calificacion=int(partes[4])
            print(nombre,apellido,edad,sexo,calificacion)
    linea=archivo.readline().strip()
```

Comment: Hola! Podrias en vez de subir foto del codigo, subir el propio codigo copy-paste?

Comment: Hola, ahora está el código sin foto, espero sirva

Answer (score 0):

El error que te devuelve el interprete es debido a que en la línea:

```
partes=linea.split(";")
```

Le estás indicando al método "`split()`" que use como delimitador el carácter: ";".

Para que funcione, las líneas de tu archivo tendrían que tener el formato:

```
"ESCUELA; CURSO"

"PROFESOR;CANTIDAD DE ALUMNOS;ALUMNOS DESTACADOS"

"NOMBRE; APELLIDO; EDAD; SEXO; CALIFICACIÓN"
```

Si no es así, cambia el parámetro que le pasas al método por el delimitador que estés usando en tu archivo.

Por ejemplo si estás usando la coma:

```
partes=linea.split(",")
```